# Why VNC not showing actual Remote Desktop

Tags: rhel, vnc

Ok i installed vnc server on RHEL 5.9 and also installed Tightvnc viewer on windows 7 and from RHEL i started vncserver and assigned the password using vncpasswd.

Then from tightvnc viewer i gave the IP and listening port xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1. It successfully connected with VNC server installed and running on RHEL. And then I gave the password and then BOOOM it gave me this hideous interface

[image]

When Actual Desktop is like this

[image]

Ok people tell me what Im missing

Comment: What you are missing is an appreciation of the minimalistic beauty of [twm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twm).

Comment: @WarrenYoung: Indeed, which is the *hideous* one again?

Comment: @sr_ maybe the minecraft screenshot on the bottom?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you see probably is **the X11 session defined in `~/.vnc/xstartup`**, a minimal X11 session, maybe something like (this is how it looks like on Debian)

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &
```

*on another display*, probably `:1`.

There're two things you can do:

- To access a different desktop that **looks the same**, you have to start it in this `xstartup` file, e.g.
  with `exec gnome-session` or something similar, have a look for
  documentation on `xinitrc` or `xsession[rc]`)
- To access **the same desktop session**, you need a different VNC server.  `x11vnc` can do *desktop sharing*; in your GNOME environment, [Vino](https://live.gnome.org/Vino) is probably the preferable choice ([as Ignacio pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61751/11539))

Comment: Great info. Just one quick question I have three users on server and I want only TWO users to have access to vnc server. root and emerg users can use the vnc. HOW TO DO THIS

Comment: (If I guessed the VNC server you use right,) you might be able to use `Xvnc` with `inetd` [as described in its man page](http://www.realvnc.com/products/open/4.1/man/Xvnc.html#lbAG) (last paragraph of the linked section).  Another (kind of high-overhead but neat) solution might be using the [Guacamole](http://guac-dev.org/) remote desktop gateway and [configuring access there](http://guac-dev.org/doc/gug/connection-setup.html).

Answer (score 7):

`vncserver` doesn't connect to the actual desktop; it creates a virtual desktop that is configured separately. If you want to access the actual desktop then you need to use either the VNC X extension or Vino.

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more information of how to do this

Comment: @Ignacio, Could you please add few details. That will definitely help beginner. Since, I couldn't understand, what to do with VNC X extension

Answer (score 5):

Please uncomment following two lines in xstartup file under `~/.vnc/xstartup`:

Before:

```
#unset SESSION_MANAGER
#exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
twm &
```

After:

```
unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
twm &
```

Comment: Please could you explain in your answer what those lines do?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue on solaris 11 and after a little search I found out the gnome desktop is not even installed. So I installed it using:

```
pkg install --accept solaris-desktop
```

Then killed the running vnc-server:

```
vncserver -kill :1
```

and after running vnc again using this command

```
vncserver -kill :1
```

I was able to see the real desktop using `vnc-viewer`.

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
gnome-session &
```

Add `gnome-session &` at the end of the xstartup file