# Desktop appears as a terminal when viewed via VNCserver client

Tags: rhel, vnc

I have installed vnc server on a RHEL 6.5 machine using the following commands:

```
yum -y install tigervnc-server xorg-x11-fonts-Type1
```

and have made the changes to the `/etc/sysconfig/vncservers` file to add the user and set the password and adjusted the resolution.

When I try to access the server via vnc client I am seeing something like this (NOT THE ORIGINAL IMAGE but a look alike) instead of the desktop:

[image: the desktop via vnc client]

I found an other issue which is relevant to the same issue, [Why VNC not showing actual Remote Desktop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61750/why-vnc-not-showing-actual-remote-desktop), but was unable to understand from it how I can make it work on a RHEL 6.4 machine.

Here is the snapshot of `/.vnc/xstartup`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: why don't you give us the original image?

Comment: the original image is also the same however it has information about my employer which should not be disclosed on public forums (company policy)

Comment: You should see the Q & A I posted earlier regarding VNC setup. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116189/vnc-server-setup-in-rhel-machines

Comment: @Ramesh i dont have any commented lines in my vi ~/.vnc/xstartup file to uncomment..

Comment: You can try uninstalling and installing as per mentioned in the above link. It would not take much time.

Comment: @Ramesh its still the same the issue persists even after following the steps mentioned in the acticle http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116189/vnc-server-setup-in-rhel-machines