# Remote desktop VNC from Ubuntu to CentOS7 showing strange view

Tags: ubuntu, centos, vnc, remote-desktop

I'm trying to use remote desktop on my LAN to access a machine's gui from another computer. The machine I am working on is Ubuntu14.04LTS using KDE desktop. The target machine is CENTOS7 with MATE desktop.

When i try to remote desktop from my Ubuntu machine using KRDC (for KDE desktop) or Vinagre using the vnc protocol, I get the following desktop:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of my settings when using Vinagre. I have the same problem when I used KRDC:

[image]

That desktop doesn't even look like the default desktop of my user (only one user on the target system). And it looks like a browser with the menu hidden. I don't know what that's about. I'm not sure what to do next for troubleshooting.

The remote machine was started as a minimum install of CENTOS7 and then the mate desktop was installed. The system currently boots fine and defaults to the mate desktop when I am in front of the machine.

The target machine has tigervnc-server installed and I'm not trying to do a desktop share. I'm trying to use the target machines GUI rather than doing everything via terminal. So what I was expecting to see was the default desktop for my user...but i got something completely different.

Can anybody provide any direction here?

If the issue is related to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61750/why-vnc-not-showing-actual-remote-desktop), can someone clarify what I need to change in CENTOS7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for the MATE desktop on a CENTOS7 system. For the user account on the target system, replace the following in `~/.vnc/xstartup`

```
#!/bin/sh

unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

with:

```
#!/bin/sh

unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
#exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
/usr/bin/mate-session

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &
```

Rebooted the target machine, and everything is working as expected.

[Source](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=99225)

This is just a solution to get it working. I still would like to find out exactly which lines above (if not all) are absolutely necessary for the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change setting in .vnc/xstartup file with

```
#!/bin/sh
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup

[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources

xsetroot -solid grey

vncconfig -iconic &

x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title 
"$VNCDESKTOP Desktop"&

mate-session &
```